# Is it possible to insert multiple names in same cell?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design

I’ve a stored procedure that will get a person’s last name and insert it under **Alias** after she updated her last name on a form.  But my boss wants to keep all previous last names whenever a person changes her name each time.  I’ve the following data in the SQL table.

```
+----------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
     PeopleID         FirstName       LastName            Alias
+-----------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+
     002112             Judy            Smith              Hall
```

Let’s say, Judy changes her last name again to Kingsley.  Is it possible to grab her previous last name Smith and insert it behind Hall under **Alias**?  I’m thinking maybe it could look like this table but have no idea how.

```
+----------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
     PeopleID         FirstName       LastName            Alias
+-----------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+
     002112             Judy          Kingsley         Hall, Smith
```

Comment: What SQL server are you working with? PostgreSQL, MySQL, or something else?

Comment: @AnthonyAtkinson: I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: If you're wanting to use normalization, you could make a completely new table called Alias and have two columns: PeopleID and Alias - and I think you can see where I'm going with this. This would allow you to have as many aliases as you need without modifying your original table. I didn't post as an answer because I'm not really an expert at normalization so I can't help much further than this description. Best of luck.

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner:  Thanks Ricky, I got what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to hold the current value in your table and create an history table to hold previous last name. Something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE last_name_history
(
   PeopleID char(6),
   from_date datetime,
   to_date datetime,
   alias char(25)
)
```

Comment: Thanks Fabien!  It's a great idea.

Answer (score -1):

Retrieve all the values in a String array. Then keep all the alias in one string separated by commas. Let us say "alias" is a String array in which different alias are stored. Now, do something like this to store it in one string-

```
for(int i=0;i<alias.length;i++)
    {
                String str="";
        if(i==0)
    str+=alias[i];
        else
            str+=","+alias[i];
    }
```

Then store the string "str" in your column "Alias".

Comment: I'm not familiar with using array.  Where will I implement your codes?

Comment: You can't do this in an SQL query, can you? If so, I'll remove my downvote. This looks like Java to me.

Comment: yes it is java.. I thought ,jdbc was implemented here. My bad.